# why do I get warning in this C code using fprintf?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, string-formatting

```
fprintf(pFile,msg.c_str());
```

why do I get a warning in Xcode :

```
Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)
```

I assume I get this warning to prevent attacks were msg contains some thing like `%s` which stream the stack to the screen until it gets to null termination. Is there any safe way to use `fprintf` in this case?

Comment: `fprintf(pFile, "%s",msg.c_str());` does it.

Comment: @DanielFischer add as answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can either give a format string,

```
fprintf(pFile, "%s", msg.c_str());
```

or use `fputs`,

```
fputs(msg.c_str(), pFile);
```

Answer (score 10):

The reason why your compiler warned you is that your way of printing a string could lead to a vulnerability called "format string exploit" if the user is able to somehow influence the contents of msg to an extend where he could put in his own format specifiers ("%n", etc). The suggested answer (fprintf(pFile, "%s", msg.c_str());) fixes this, as the format string is now constant.

You can read more about format string exploits on here: http://julianor.tripod.com/bc/formatstring-1.2.pdf